# Do something with properties while destructuring

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring

I am often dealing with a situation where I want to call the same method on the properties of some object before I destructure them. For example, I will have a record in which some properties have a method to return value from a signal/callback and others have the same method which returns just a plain value. I would like to destructure them such that I end up with the values only:

```
type ValueLike<T> = { value(): T };

const cb = () => 50;
const aProp: ValueLike<number> = { value: () => cb() };
const bProp: ValueLike<number> = { value: () => 100 };

const props = { a: aProp, b: bProp };
const { a, b } = props // Want to end up with { a: 50, b: 100 };
```

Of course, I could write some helper function, called something like `unwrapAll()`, that takes an object, calls `.value()` on each property, assigns those to a new object, and then destructure that. However, I'm wondering whether there's some way to avoid having to create the intermediate object, without having to assign each property separately (i.e. `const a = props.a.value(), const b = props.b.value(), ...`)

Comment: The destructuring assignment only really does one thing. It takes some sort of *structured* data and then *pulls it apart* or "de-structures" it into pieces. That is it, it doesn't change or mutate the pieces. Any time you think "I have some data, I want a subset of it" then you can use destructuring. If you think "I have some data I want to *change it*" then that's not what destructuring does.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it does make sense that it works that way, I was just wondering if there wasn't some trick to get around that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do additional process while destructuring an object.

However there's an approach similar to deleted answer that uses getter functions to achieve your goal. It inevitably creates an intermediate object, just the `value()` gets called only when destructured.

```js
function wrap(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => 
    Object.defineProperty(acc, k, { get() {
      return v.value();
    }}), {});
}

const cb = () => 50;
const aProp = { value: () => cb() };
const bProp = { value: () => 100 };

const props = wrap({ a: aProp, b: bProp });
const { a, b } = props;

console.log(a, b);
```

Comment: The object given to `wrap` does not necessarily have `.value` on each of its values. Consider `{ a: { value: () => 1, b: 2, c: null }`. This currently only handles `{ a: { value: () => 1, b: { value: 2 }, c: { value: null } }`. This can probably work but should be restricted by TS to only allow something at least like `Record<PropertyKey, { value: unknown }>`. Or `wrap` should handle objects that are not shaped like this. Also, worth noting, it only handles a single level, and not nesting `data = { a: { b: { value: () => 42 } } }` destructured as `const { a: { b } } = data;`

Comment: Yes, this answer is based on the original `props` is always the type of `Record<PropertyKey, ValueLike>`, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: No, it's not only considering just `ValueLike` since that interface always has a *method* called `value`. Having a *non-callable property* called `value` is not what the interface describes.

Comment: Ah, you’re right. In that case the type check is unnecessary. Just fixed it according to the type notification.